# Building a First Run Installer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I'd like to build a web installer into my ASP.NET MVC application. It would be a first run installer that would allow the user to create a user account, set database connection strings, and configure some first run settings. I was looking at SPA's like HotTowel and OAK. Any advice on a good direction to go would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this myself but I know Orchard CMS http://www.orchardproject.net/ has similar to what you require. Reviewing their code might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll review the source code in Orchard CMS.